# ORACLE APEX PL/SQL, Values are inserting Itself when it should be stopped by a trigger

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I want to know why my user-defined exception is not working. The goal is to create a trigger where it will fire before an insert or update on the employee table.
Inside the trigger is a procedure call where it will check whether the salary is within the acceptable range.

This is my procedure code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_SALARY(
    t_job_id IN EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID%TYPE,
    t_sal IN EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE
)
IS
    min_sal JOBS.MIN_SALARY%TYPE;
    max_sal JOBS.MAX_SALARY%TYPE;
    sal_error EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT MIN_SALARY, MAX_SALARY
    INTO min_sal, max_sal
    FROM JOBS
    WHERE JOB_ID = t_job_id;
    IF t_sal > max_sal OR t_sal < min_sal THEN
    RAISE sal_error;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN sal_error THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Invalid Salary. Salaries for ' || t_job_id || ' must be between ' || min_sal || ' and ' || max_sal || '.');
END;
```

This is my trigger code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_SALARY_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    t_job_id EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID%TYPE;
    t_sal EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
    t_job_id := :NEW.JOB_ID;
    t_sal := :NEW.SALARY;
    CHECK_SALARY(t_job_id, t_sal);
END;
```

And this is the anonymous block where I try to insert the values

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID, JOB_ID, SALARY)
    VALUES (777, 'IT_DBADM', 20000);
END;
```

The initial error I had was that the last_name column on the employee is not nullable. So I made the last_name column nullable. It seemed to work fine but the values still inserted into the table.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the exception handling. When I changed it to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. It worked fine. But it is bugging me what is wrong with the first method that I used.

Comment: Please comment if something is not clear then I will edit the post to put the needed information.

Comment: Just as a general comment:  in a real life APEX application, this will never ever be done in a trigger. It would be handled with a validation on the form. If your assignment is to write a trigger: good job. If you assignment is to check salary in an application: call the ```check_salary``` function in a validation on the form where the record is created/edited

Comment: Oh it was just an assignment regarding triggers. Now that you said it, you're most likely right about it being handled the validation form. I was just frustrated with the exception not working so I asked here for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the row from being inserted, your trigger would need to throw an exception.  In the code you posted, your procedure is raising and then catching the exception.  As far as the trigger is aware, there is no error so the insert is allowed.

You could remove the exception handler from your procedure.  That would cause the trigger to raise an error and the `insert` would fail.  But the error stack wouldn't provide a whole lot of information that would make it obvious to the user what the problem was.  The `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` approach you reference is likely the better solution because it lets you specify a meaningful error message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It enlightened me. So the problem is in how oracle handles the error?

Comment: @user22155495 - I'm not sure quite what you're saying.  If your procedure catches the exception and does not re-raise it, there is no longer an exception.  That's basically how exceptions are handled in every language ever.  If you want your trigger to prevent the `insert` from happening, it needs to throw an exception.  Whether you do that by not catching the exception in the procedure, re-raising the exception in the procedure, raising a different exception in the procedure, etc. is up to you.